# Use result of function without repeatedly evaluating

Tags: function-construction, linear-algebra, functional-style

I have a function which takes the determinant of a matrix whose values depend on two parameters:

```
f[x_,y_]:= Det[M[x,y]];
```

where M is a predetermined matrix which is numerical aside from the inputs x,y. The result f(x,y) is a polynomial in x,y. The issue I have is computational speed. I need to check, for a large number of points, the value of the determinant. But computing the determinant of the matrix numerically at each point is unnecessary. Instead, I want to compute the determinant symbolically with (x,y), then simply evaluate the resultant polynomial at the points in question. This seems to be orders of magnitude faster.

The issue is that defining the function as above makes Mathematica evaluate the determinant whenever I plug in explicit values (x,y). I can of course evaluate f(x,y) on symbolic variables x,y, then copy/paste the resultant polynomial into the defintion of a new function. But I would like to automate this process. Is there any way to define a function which is the result of evaluating f(x,y), without having to call the original function and re-evaluating the determinant?

Comment: Either change `SetDelayed` to `Set`, i.e., `f[x_,y_] =  ...` or `Evaluate` the RHS of the definition, i.e., `f[x_,y_] := Evaluate[ ... ]`

Comment: Hulsey, is there any way you can give an example or dummy matrix for `M` that possible solutions can be used on? It would help to see how the memory usage scales with some methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can always memoize the result, assuming you aren't going to have millions of different inputs that you don't want cached:

```
f[x_,y_]:= f[x, y] = Det[M[x,y]]
```

So for any given input the call to `Det` is only evaluated once, and subsequent calls will used the already-evaluated result.

Comment: Unfortunately millions of inputs is exactly what I want...